# Loss of context. Closure

Tags: javascript

```
var user = {
    firstName: "Alex",
    sayHi: function() {
        alert(this.firstName);
    }
};

setTimeout(function() {
    user.sayHi(); // Alex
}, 1000);
```

They say that the user gets from the closure.

Do I understand correctly that the method user.sayHi wrapped in a function that is declared in the global context, and that has access to the user object? This forms a closure?

Comment: this isn't an issue with a closure.

Comment: kind of, its the function inside the sayHi that is the closure, but the method isn't a closure because its globally available. if you defined anything inside the sayHi(), then that would be a closure and outside of global scope

Comment: Every function in JS is a closure, because every function has access to the bindings defined in ancestor scopes. I recommend to read the Wikipedia article if you want to learn the definition of a closure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`user.sayHi()` is wrapped in an anonymous function which is in the global scope`. This anonymous function creates a closure, though the closure is of no consequence in this case. Since the anonymous function is in the global scope, and the user in the global scope, the anonymous function has access to the user object.

Comment: You must have misunderstood. Sorry for my English. I have read that this code works, as user gets from closure.

So try to understand where is the closure.

And he came to the conclusion that the method user.sayHi wrapped in an anonymous function, and this anonymous function is declared in the global context, and she in turn has access to the object user.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov I think so.